# Select screen in AS3

Tags: click, actionscript-3

is it possible to do one click in AS3 ?

I want simulate a click, like an auto-clicker program.

Sorry for my bad english, and thank you for you're answer

Comment: please explain a bit more of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I try to simulate a click. In an event, I want my program do one auto click without interraction user

Comment: Yes.  You have to code what the button does when user clicks so you can just do that code without the click.  That's only within the Flash swf.  You can't make javascript or the browser receive a click.

Comment: You have an SWF file that has clickable buttons, but you want the "after click" code to happen without actual user click?? In that cse just put the "after click" code inside a function example `function testClick() :void { /* your code here */ }` now whenever you want it to happen just run the function using `testClick();` and everything in that function will happen as though user had clicked..

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch mouse click event for that button. Following example shows custom event, this would give you fair idea how to dispatch it.

[Dispatching event](http://www.as3blog.org/2010/03/11/how-to-dispatch-a-custom-event/)

Dispatch click event of your button.